# Link generic ObservableMap and MapChangeListener

Tags: java, javafx

I'm currently having issues to understand how to properly link an `ObservableMap` with the `MapChangeListener`.

I need to create a generic `ObservableMap` because I will have different maps with different key/value types to display on my views.

What I've done so far :

The map :

```
public class DrawableMap<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V>, implements ObservableMap<K, V> 
{
    private ArrayList<MapChangeListener<K, V>> observerList = new ArrayList<>();

    DrawableMap()
    {
         super();
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(MapChangeListener listener)
    {
          observerList.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeListener(MapChangeListener listener)
    {
          observerList.remove(listener);
    }
```

The view :

```
public class View<K, V> implements MapChangeListener<K, V>
{
     @Override
     OnChanged(Change<? extends K, ? extends V> arg)
     { 
          //Don't know what to put in here.
     }
}
```

I'm not really sure to use the generics as they are supposed to be used.

For example, one view will display some Shape nodes on a Panel. These Shape will be stored on the map as keys. But I'm struggling to understand how to notify the observers, and once the notification received, check what has changed to update the views. When is `onChanged` called?

Am I supposed to create a `notifyOberserver()` method inside my `DrawableMap`? 
Something like:

```
public void notifyObservers()
    {
          for(MapChangeListener listener : observerList)
          {
               //Do something
          }
    }
```

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Why are you creating your own `ObservableMap` rather than creating one via `FXCollections`?

Comment: First of all: the signature of the `onChanged` method is wrong. It needs to be `public void onChanged(MapChangeListener.Change<? extends K, ? extends V>)` and only you know how to react to modifications of the map. `onChanged` is called every time you modify the map, e.g. by adding a new key/value pair, modify the value of a existing mapping or removeing a mapping. This means extending from `HashMap` you need to override every single method for modifying the map, even the `entrySet`.

Comment: Doesn't [`FXCollections.observableHashMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableHashMap--) do what you need?

Comment: @fabian and Slaw :  Yes FXCollections is exactly what I need, I didn't find that searching for ObservableMap on Google, that's why I thought the common practice was to create one with the interfaces. Thank you very much !